# How do I make a jump reach the same height even when starting from a different Y position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm trying to allow my player to jump mid-air while it's touching a floating sphere and the way I have my player jumping is by directly setting the velocity to 17.26.

The player can jump in mid-air as long as you are touching the sphere; meaning that if you were to jump from the top of the sphere, the total height of the jump would be different to when you are jumping from the bottom of the sphere.

I think the best way to keep the jump height consistent is to offset the initial velocity depending on how far you are from the sphere's center. So I've done some research on forumulas for how to calculate how much velocity is required to reach a specific height and how to calculate the peak of a jump from the initial velocity.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that was exactly correct. I found:

```
Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravity * height)
```

but this doesn't take drag into account. I would also need to calculate the peak of the jump from the initial velocity and add the difference of the sphere's center and the player's position from the beginning of the jump to get the height value.

Then I found:

```
heightOfJump = (0.5f * gravity * Mathf.Abs(velocity.y / gravity)) + (velocity.y * Mathf.Abs(velocity.y / gravity))
```

and this doesn't take drag into account either. After testing this with drag set to 0 it didn't seem to be correct anyway.

I've been trying to come up with a formula to change the jumpHeight with a multiplier depending on how far the player is to the center of the floating sphere, so that no matter where the player's Y is at the start of the jump, the peak of the jump stays consistent. I feel like this is just a simple physics formula that I cannot find.

This is the code that let's my player jump.

```
float jumpHeight = 17.26f;

playerRigidbody.velocity -= new Vector3(0, playerRigidbody.velocity.y, 0); //Set player's Y velocity to 0

playerRigidbody.velocity += jumpHeight * Vector3.up;
```

Gravity is -9.81 and the gravity scale is 7
playerRigidbody.drag is set to 1
Time.fixedDeltaTime is 0.01666667, just in case that matters
And the player's jump consistently peaks at 1.733022 when starting from a Y of 0

Here is a picture that I've been staring at for the past 2 days
[im dumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97iMr.png)

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach for achieving a consistent peak jump can be to measure the time that it takes the player to reach the peak of the jump from a certain position and use that time to calculate the initial velocity required to reach the peak of the jump with the desired jump height. You can store that time and use it every time the player jumps so the player will reach the peak in the same amount of time, therefore providing a consistent jump.

You can use following code to do this:

```
float timeToPeak = measureTimeToPeak(); //measure time to peak
float jumpHeight = 17.26f;
float initialVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(2 * gravity * jumpHeight) * timeToPeak; 
playerRigidbody.velocity -= new Vector3(0, playerRigidbody.velocity.y, 0);
playerRigidbody.velocity += initialVelocity * Vector3.up;
```

Comment: This is the same formula that I tried before. I wasn't able to find out how to take drag into account and I needed to calculate the peak of the jump from the initial jumpHeight; since I wanted it to be consistent with the regular jumping.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the timeToPeak part, but this seems more inconsistent than the first answer. Is there any way to include drag in the formula?